# Ocaml - Generate list of all char values

Tags: ocaml

I have been trying to find a simple way to get a list of all possible char values (i.e. ['\000';'\001';...;'\255']) in OCaml.

In Python I'd do a simple list comprehension like:

```
[chr(x) for x in range(255)]
```

However, the way I currently know in OCaml is much less simple:

```
all_chrs = let rec up_to = fun lst max -> 
  match lst with
  | [] -> failwith "Invalid_input"
  | hd::tl ->
    let up = hd + 1 in
    if up = max then up::lst
    else up_to (up::lst) max
in let all_ascii = up_to [0] 255
in List.map Char.chr all_ascii
```

Can anyone point me to the simplest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you need that list for?

Comment: @PatJ I'm doing some work with MetaOcaml and I needed a partially static representation of a character, which could be one of a number of candidate characters. The representation I am using is a pair (char code * char list) where the list represents all of the possible values for the character.

Comment: maybe you'd want to use sets and maps instead. From what you say, I don't understand why you'd need to start with a complete list of all characters.

Comment: as a side comment, the `all_ascii` is not the same as all chars, it is only 128 characters that have codes that range from 0 to 127 inclusive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With OCaml 4.06, using `List.init`, you can do it pretty easily:

```
let l = List.init 256 Char.chr
```

On older versions of OCaml, you'll need a bit more code:

```
let l =
 let rec aux i acc =
  if i < 0 then acc else aux (i-1) (Char.chr i::acc)
 in aux 255 []
```

Update: from Martin Jambon's comment:

```
let l = Array.to_list (Array.init 256 Char.chr)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I am not using 4.06 but the second method is still much cleaner than what I had before. That first option is really nice though, much closer to what I was hoping for.

Comment: @JamesAllingham I'd do `Array.to_list (Array.init 256 Char.chr)`. This works with older versions of OCaml too.

Answer (score 5):

If using extended standard libraries doesn't scare you, with [containers](https://github.com/c-cube/ocaml-containers/):

```
CCList.(map Char.chr @@ range 0 255)
```

You can do the same with batteries, base, and others.

Comment: In Batteries: `range 0 \`To 255`.  In Base or Core: `range 0 256`.  (Drup, what does `@@` do?)

Comment: @Drup for this work I prefered a solution without extended standard libraries, but I'll  keep your solution in mind in future - Thanks!

Comment: @Mars `f @@ expr` is the same as `f (expr)` so you could rewrite it with parens as `map Char.chr (range 0 255)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining that, @PatJ.

Answer (score 0):

A short version in pure vanila OCaml. Not tail recursive but demonstrates the functional nature of OCaml:

```
let rec range n = if n < 0 then [] else n :: range (n - 1)
let chars = List.rev_map Char.chr (range 255)
```

Comment: A small note from the future. As of OCaml 4.14 and later: `let[@tail_mod_cons] rec range n = if n < 0 then [] else n :: range (n - 1)`. Now `range` is tail-recursive.